# Strongly Typed View in Spark View Engine and MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, spark-view-engine

I am having a play around with the different view engines that one can use with ASP.net MVC. I am trying out Spark, but I am stuck on how I can get my View to be Strongly typed.

I have done the following:

```
<viewdata message="string" model="ComparingViewsSparkEngine.Models.LogOnModel" />
```

And within my view I have changed anything like this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
```

to be Sparky like so:

```
${Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)}
```

But I am getting an error that says:

> Dynamic view compilation failed.
>   c:\Users\Ciwan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ComparingViewsSparkEngine\ComparingViewsSparkEngine\Views\Account\LogOn.spark(19,17): error CS1056: Unexpected character '$'

Comment: have you added the spark view engine in your global.ascx

Comment: I have, since my other Spark pages show fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

As of the last version of the code you have this:

```
${using (Html.BeginForm()) {
```

it needs to change to this:

```
#using (Html.BeginForm()) {
```

because you're trying to write a line of pure C# code. And also then your last line can be `#}` instead of `#}}`

---

Not sure if this is the problem - but it looks like you haven't closed the `}` on Validation Summary on line 11.

And I'm pretty sure you'll also have to end the view with `#}}` rather than `}}` because the `#` denotes a raw line of code when you don't have a `$` to start the code off.

To get around the ugly `#}}` stuff, I usually use [Spark Bindings](http://sparkviewengine.com/documentation/bindings) - you can check out my [blog post](http://blog.robertgreyling.com/2010/08/spark-bindings-are-you-tired-of-eating.html) on it.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I added the missing closing curly brace, and added the # sign, but still getting errors :( This time it says [ LogOn.spark(19,17): error CS1056: Unexpected character '$']

Comment: Sorry Rob. I have now. Please help :(

Comment: Here is a [screenshot of the error](http://img837.imageshack.us/img837/5307/errornb.jpg).

Comment: Thanks Robert, even the updated answer didn't work I'm afraid. I get [this](http://goo.gl/Dvpjc)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I couldn't get the using this to work:

```
${using (Html.BeginForm()) {
```

So instead I just used regular HTML form tags and it now works:

```
<form> // form stuff here </form>
```

Not ideal, but at least I'm not getting the error, and the page seems to be working.

Thanks